# Runnable jar with jvm args

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I was trying to create a runnable jar file using Eclipse.
The problem is that the vm parameters I have added to the run configuration in the Eclipse were not saved in any way.

I know I can create a batch file that will run the jar with the needed arguments, but I would prefer my users will just run the jar itself.

My question is therefore, is there any way to pass vm arguments to the runnable jar not by command line?

Comment: no, i'm afraid this is not possible. i guess you need to make a bat-file to launch the jar with your vm arguments

Comment: I had a feeling that was the situation. 

Thank you.

Comment: Netbeans can do it if you go into project properties and change arguments

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, you can't do this without some form of wrapper. You can write a .bat file and/or a .sh script to invoke the JVM with appropriate settings.

You may also want to check out [JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp), which provides a means to wrap a .jar with executable params and let it run as a standalone *or* service (despite its name). It has a set of features to allow you to control the JVM execution in a variety of fashions.

Comment: This isn't true. Eclipse comes with a jarinjarloader set of classes that, when embedded in a .jar file will cause the .jar to be executable.

Comment: I know this is possible with Netbeans, sad eclipse can't do it

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't the .bat and .sh script options require that the user have a JDK installed, as opposed to a JRE?

Comment: No. You just need a JRE, since all you need to invoke is the java runtime executable